# So what if there's no Kohen for Miriam?

Tags: kohen-priest, behaalotcha-parsha, tzaraas-negaim, miriam

In [Rashi's second explanation](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.12.12.4?lang=he) of Behaaloscha 12:12, he says

> אִם אֵינְךָ רוֹפְאָהּ בִּתְפִלָּה, מִי מַסְגִּירָהּ,מִי מְטַהֲרָהּ? אֲנִי אִ"אֶ לִרְאוֹתָהּ, שֶׁאֲנִי קָרוֹב וְאֵין קָרוֹב רוֹאֶה אֶת הַנְּגָעִים, וְכֹהֵן אַחֵר אֵין בָּעוֹלָם, וְזֶהוּ אשר בצאתו מרחם אמו: ‏
>
> if you don't cure her through prayer, who will quarantine her and who will make her pure again?  I can't, because she's my relative and a relative can't rule about tzaraas [[this is Rabbi Meir's opinion; we don't rule like him](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Negaim.2.5?lang=he&p2=Mishneh_Torah,_Defilement_by_Leprosy.9.1&lang2=he)], and there's no other Kohen in the world to do it.

But someone with tzaraas doesn't become tamei until a Kohen proclaims him so.  If there's no Kohen eligible to do it, there are no halachic consequences.  So what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe they thought the Tzaraat process provided a cure?